# connecting my Ubuntu to mor screens via a dell d3000 docking station

Tags: drivers, 20.04, docking

I have a dell laptop with an ubuntu operating system. i also have a dell d3000 docking station. when connecting my laptop to the docking station the computer recognize the dock, connects the muse, keyboard etc, but he dose not recognize the extra monitors connected.
what can I do to fix it? any specific driver I need to install?

Comment: What version Ubuntu? How are the extra monitors connected? Display port? HDMI? USB?

Comment: version 20.04.1.
one monitor is connected to the docking station via HDMI, and another with a VGA.
the docking station is connected to the laptop with a usb 3 cable.